# document.getElementById value does not persist

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a date input field like so ...

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" id="reg_dob_val" name="dob" value="">
```

I'm attempting to set the value of the field like so ...

```js
browser.execute(function () {
    document.getElementById('reg_dob_val').value = '01/01/1901'
})
```

I can see that the value is set.  However, as soon as I tab to another field the value goes away.  How do I get the value to persist?

Comment: Where is `browser.execute` coming from?

Comment: Most likely tab is triggering some function which is resetting the value or  it is triggering a rerender. Please share more details if that i not the case.

Comment: This command (browser.execute) is part of a Nightwatch test (a javascript framework based on Selenium) that is filling out a registration form.  I can use a 'setValue' command to set the date and this works fine in Chrome.  However, setValue doesn't work in Firefox (this is a known issue), so I was trying to find a workaround.  I don't necessarily have to "tab".  Simply entering a value into another field once the date has been set will result in the date value getting cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code and check for functions where this field 'reg_dob_val' is being reset like,

```
onkeypress/keydown/keyup, focus/blur events
```

Apply breakpoint and investigate the call-stack using dev-tools